# ORA-04098: trigger 'SYSTEM.ON_INSERT' is invalid and failed re-validation

Tags: database, plsql, triggers

I am trying to create a simple trigger. My aim is to create ON-INSERT trigger for the scenario where on admission of the patient in the hospital, there was some past due (based on his past admittance) and print that due.

```
create or replace trigger insert_patient
after insert 
on appontment_info
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
   d number;
BEGIN 

  select DUE into d from PATIENT_INFO where pid = :new.p_id;
  dbms_output.put_line('due of the patient:'||d);
END;
```

But when I run:

```
insert into appontment_info (p_id,pname,doc_name)values(2,'viju','Abc');
```

to activate the trigger, I get this error message:

```
    ORA-04098: trigger 'SYSTEM.ON_INSERT' is invalid and failed re-validation
```

I don't understand whats causes this error. Do you know what causes this error? Or why this is happening?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The problem is that there is a trigger in the SYSTEM schema named `ON_INSERT` which is not valid, and which apparently needs to be executed in order to compile your new trigger. Check with your DBA's...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer

```
select DUE into d from PATIENT_INFO where patient_info.pid = :new.p_id;
```

Thank you Bob Jarvis